# ServletOutputStream display Print dialog box

Tags: java, servlets, printing, dialog, outputstream

Is it possible to display print box like below image  for ServletOutputStream?

[image: print box]

I've a javascript which is will open new window, and it open the Servlet. Like below code

`window.open("${pageContext.request.contextPath}/PrintingPDF?id="+data)`

In servlet PrintingPDF I set the contenttype to application/pdf. So once the pdf load in the new window I want to display the print dialog box. below are my code in servlet PrintingPDF.

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        //response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        ServletOutputStream out = null;
        FileInputStream in = null;
        BufferedInputStream bis = null;
        BufferedOutputStream bos = null;

        try {

            String id = request.getParameter("id");         
            String downloadPath = ConfigUtil.getParameter("downloadpath");

            in = new FileInputStream(downloadPath + "/"+ id +".pdf");
            if(in!=null){
                response.setContentType("application/pdf");
                out = response.getOutputStream();
                bis = new BufferedInputStream(in);
                bos = new BufferedOutputStream(out);

                int ch = 0;
                while((ch=bis.read())!=-1){
                    bos.write(ch);
                }
            }

        }catch(DocumentException docEx){
            log.debug("document exception :: " + docEx.getMessage());
        }catch(Exception ex){
            log.debug("Exception ex :: " + ex.getMessage());
        }finally {
            bis.close();
            bos.close();
            in.close();
            out.close();
        }
    }
```

Hope someone can assist me.

Comment: That is a browser window. You need to go read up on how HTTP works.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I disagree. He needs to read up on how a **browser** works first.